# Initializing an array with elements of another array in R

Tags: r, arrays, rstudio, initializing

I have an array

```
a<-c(6,77,98,88,3,10,7,5)
```

I want to initialize another array with the 1st, 6th, and 8th element i.e. b should look as follows:

```
b = (6,10,5)
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this in R?

(I am a beginner, as I am sure you understand, on stack overflow as much as on R. I couldn't find the exact thing I am looking for - maybe I am using the wrong terms to search.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use indexing in `replace`.  Assuming that we need a vector with `length` 8, initialize with `numeric` (gives a vector of 0's), then `replace` using an index with the vector 'b'

```
replace(numeric(8), c(1, 6, 8), b)
#[1]  6  0  0  0  0 10  0  5
```

If we need to initialize as missing values

```
replace(rep(NA_integer_, 8), c(1, 6, 8), b)
```

---

If we want to extract 1, 6, 8 elements from 'a'

```
b <- a[c(1, 6, 8)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to initialize b? I am getting an error `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`

Comment: @Nilima updated the post. I think you are creating the 'b' based on index.  in that case, just use index to subset the 'a'